# Error while reading JSON url in nsstring

Tags: iphone, json

i am sending one url to the server 
http://ogcitsco.w05.winhost.com/Service.svc/getsubmenu/south indian/restaurant/Lunch 
in which i am getting  bad url response, since there is one space between two words south indian, how should i work with that, i have tried to remove the space and passed the url however in response getting null value, when i paste the above url into browser it is showing the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to encode your URL first: `[@"http://ogcitsco.w05.winhost.com/Service.svc/getsubmenu/south indian/restaurant/Lunch" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: thanks xan , i have tried the information what you have given, but it didn't work,it passes the url, however in response getting null value i have implemented the following thing         NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ogcitsco.w05.winhost.com/Service.svc/getsubmenu/south indian/restaurant/Lunch"];
        
        valueString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

a space can be changed to %20 for most languages (or + is possible too i beleve)